# in linux, is it possible to find out the hard disk operation time

Tags: linux

in my Linux machine, it has 4 partitions.hda1,hda2,hda3,hda4.i ahve an script to mount each partition dynamically .i want to calculate the operational time (ie, Operational is defined as the disk is mounted). Is it possible to do this.If so, how to verify this.

Comment: do you mean how long the disk is mounted or how long it takes to mount the drive?

Comment: yes ...  how long the disk is mounted

Comment: It won't be possible to do it reliably, but you can log the mount and umounting time and analyze that. It would work as long as you never had unexpected shutdown where you didn't have a chance to umount properly. If you had unexpected shutdown, you may be able to get by with checking the last journal time, though I don't know how you'd get that unless you modify the kernel/filesystem driver. More importantly though, why do you want to do this? I'm guessing you have some sort of XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

For ext2 / ext3 / ext4 partitions you can use `dumpe2fs` to find out when the partition was mounted :

```
# dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda1  | grep 'Last mount time'
Last mount time:          Sun Feb 15 19:08:06 2015
```

Using this [datediff](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24636) function to take the time difference with current date, you get the number of days it's been mounted :

```
$ date
Thu Mar  5 09:07:32 CET 2015
$ datediff  'Thu Mar  5 09:07:32 CET 2015'  'Sun Feb 15 19:08:06 2015'
17 days
```

---

Or if the partition is mounted at boot time and doesn't get unmounted you could just use `uptime` :

```
$ uptime
09:17:23 up 17 days, 13:10,  8 users,  load average: 0.51, 0.51, 0.40
```